# RTK Query -- protected endpoints with public endpoints

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have a fairly simple application where I want the public to be able to see all posts, but I want the user to be authenticated to create and delete only their post.

When I set it up like this, I get an error, "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'token') buildThunks.ts:448" and can't fetch posts until logged in.

I'm fairly new to RTK Query. Is there a way to allow an unauthenticated user to use just getPosts and getPost?

Thanks

```
export const postApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: "postApi",
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "http://localhost:3001",
    prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
        const token = ( (getState()).auth.user.token )
        if(token){
            headers.set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
            return headers
        }
    },
    }),
    tagTypes: ["Post"],
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getPosts: builder.query({
            query: ()=> ({
                url: "/api/posts",
                method: 'GET'
            }),
            providesTags: ["Post"]
        }),
        getPost: builder.query({
            query: (id) => ({
                url: `/api/posts/:${id}`,
                method: 'GET'
            }),
            providesTags: ['Post']
        }),
        createPost: builder.mutation({
            query: (formData) => ({
                url: "/api/posts",
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            }),
            invalidatesTags: ["Post"]
        }),
        deletePost: builder.mutation({
            query: (id) => ({
                url: `/api/posts/${id}`,
                method: 'DELETE',
                body: id
            }),
            invalidatesTags: ["Post"]
            
        })
    })

})

export const { useGetPostsQuery, useGetPostQuery, useCreatePostMutation, useDeletePostMutation } = postApi
```

Routes

```
import express from 'express'
import { deletePost, getPost, getPosts, newPost } from '../controllers/Post.js'
import { auth } from '../middleware/auth.js'

const router = express.Router()

//get posts
router.get('/', getPosts)

//get post
router.get('/:id', getPost)

//create psot
router.post('/', auth, newPost)

//delete post
router.delete('/:id', auth, deletePost)

export default router
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More of a general JavaScript question to be honest ;)

You are trying to access `getState()).auth.user.token`, while `state.auth.user` in your case is `null`.

You can write it as `getState()).auth.user?.token`, and it will not error and just return `undefined` if there is no `.user` property (or it is `null`).

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I feel foolish for not thinking of that